# What's the correct Schema.org type for an HR consulting business?

Tags: schema.org

It is unclear if I should be using `ProfessionalService`, `LocalBusiness`, or `Service`. It is a human resource consulting business with an array of services for small business employers.

```html
<div itemtype="https://schema.org/Service">
  <h2><strong>Our</strong> Services</h2>
  <h4>Strategic planning</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum ….</p>
  <h4>Employee Handbooks and safety manuals</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum ….</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

([`ProfessionalService`](http://schema.org/ProfessionalService) is deprecated.)

[`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness) is for the business (name, address, etc.), and [`Service`](http://schema.org/Service) for a service provided by this business.